# how to catch the selected attachment items from contex menu inside outlook attachment menu

Tags: delphi, outlook, email-attachments

i develop in Delphi 10.3 (RIO), writen outlook add-in using add-in-express ver 9.x
i want to chach just "selected" files from attachment list.

i add button to adxRibbonContextMenu object,
when i click on the right button with the mouse on one (selected) or more files from the attachment list,
i want to be able to get just the selected one (one or more).

i sow some solution in VB or C# - how to chatc AttachmentSelection object.
but i can not see how to translate it to Delphi.

i tried something like :

```
Var
  AttachmentSelection: OleVariant;
  ExploreeSelection: OleVariant;
  ISelection: Selection;
  i,j: integer;
  IExpl: _Explorer;
  VIntf: OleVariant;
  Intf: Outlook2000._MailItem;
begin
  AttachmentSelection := OleVariant(RibbonControl.Context);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(AttachmentSelection.Class));
  if AttachmentSelection.Class = 169 then // olAttachmentSelection = 169
  begin
    for i := 1 to AttachmentSelection.Count do begin
      ShowMessage(AttachmentSelection.Item(i).FileName);
    end;
  end
  else
  if AttachmentSelection.Class = 34 then
  begin // olExplorer = 34

    IExpl := OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
    ISelection := nil;
    if Assigned(IExpl) then
    try
      try
          ISelection := IExpl.Selection;
      except
          // "The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations"
        ISelection := nil;
      end;
    finally
      IExpl := nil;
    end;

    if Assigned(ISelection) then
    Try
      for i := 1 to ISelection.Count do
      begin
          //ShowMessage(ISelection.item(i));

        VIntf := ISelection.Item(i);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(VIntf.Class));

        if ((VIntf.Class = olAttachment) or (VIntf.Class = olAttachments)) Then
        begin
          ShowMessage('olAttachment or olAttachments');
        end
        else
        if (VIntf.Class = olMail)  Then
        begin
          ShowMessage('olMail');
          IDispatch(Intf) := Self.OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i);
          for j := 1 to Intf.Attachments.count do
          begin // this is not the selected list. it just "ALL THE LIST"

          end;
        end;

        VIntf := Unassigned;
      end;
    finally
      ISelection := nil;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    //ShowMessage('Not an AttachmentSelection');
  end;
end;
```

but this give me the all list and i can't find any property of "selected" in the attachment item.
i look at IMIBO (extended mapi) and didn't find any solution there also.

did some one able to get this list?

in C# the code is : From https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=13763

```
object context = control.Context; 
if (context is Outlook._Explorer) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("EXPLORER"); 
    Outlook._Explorer window = context as Outlook._Explorer; 
    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + window.AttachmentSelection.Count); 
    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, window.AttachmentSelection); 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(window.AttachmentSelection); 
} 
else if (context is Outlook._Inspector) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("INSPECTOR"); 
    Outlook._Inspector window = context as Outlook._Inspector; 
    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + window.AttachmentSelection.Count); 
    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, window.AttachmentSelection); 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(window.AttachmentSelection); 
} 
else if (context is Outlook._AttachmentSelection) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("ATTACHMENTSELECTION"); 
    Outlook._AttachmentSelection attSelection = context as Outlook._AttachmentSelection; 
    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + attSelection.Count); 
    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, attSelection); 
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attSelection); 
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the C# code you translated to Delphi.

Comment: hi fpiette, thanks. i edit my Q, i think the problem is that i can't find equivalent to Outlook._AttachmentSelection

Answer (score 1):

`AttachmentSelection` is defined in `Outlook2010` while you use `Outlook2000`. Just change you uses clause from Outlook2000 to Outlook2010 and aslo everywhere you mention Outlook2000.

Comment: u was right about the outlok2000 :), i did found the _AttachmentSelection in outlook2010.

Comment: @mazluta When you'll confirm, mark my answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: this did not help. plaese see the "answer" of my own. (how can i replay to your answer?). i also tried to put outlookapplication and connect it to outlook and try to take the selection of the attachmentselectionlist, but alwes get just the first one.

Comment: Add to your question a MRE (minimal reproducible example). I have no time to type all the stuff to test your problem. Edit your question the .pas and .dfm files. If you do, I'll try it.

Comment: hi fpiette, i don't no how to add MRE and can't found button to do it in the page. so i put it in : http://www.hanibaal.co.il/dwn/sof/mz-priority-dll.zip (full project - not big).

Comment: its includ Extended mapi unit as "uses". if u dont have that just delete those lines. after compile and install, you will see the addin in outlook. the event how fail is : SaveAttachmentsControls0Click from SaveAttachments control how appere on mouse right click on the attachment

Comment: @mazluta to add the MRE, just copy/paste the source code (.pas) into the question in edit mode. For the DFM, you first have to display it in text mode in the IDE then copy/paste to the message. Know know how to do that since you already added code to your question.

Comment: By the way, I can't do anything since you MRE makes reference to adxAddIn that I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Explorer.AttachmentSelection` collection. `AttachmentSelection.Class` property is `169 (OlObjectClass.olAttachmentSelection)`.

Answer (score -1):

hi fpiette / Dmitry / All

i tried this. but i alwes return just the first selected item (mybe not the selected ??)

```
procedure TAddInModule.SaveAttachmentsControls0Click(Sender: TObject;
  const RibbonControl: IRibbonControl);
var
  Context             : OleVariant;
  Explorer            : OleVariant;
  AttachmentSelection : _AttachmentSelection;
  count, i            : Integer;
  AttFileName         : String;
  FileName            : String;
  JustFileName        : String;
  attList             : TStringList;
  FileLength          : Integer;
  TakeIt              : Boolean;
begin
  // click on the menu entry of the attachment contextmenu


//if (context is OutlookApp.Explorers) Then
//begin
//    MessageBox.Show("EXPLORER");
//    Outlook._Explorer window = context as Outlook._Explorer;
//    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + window.AttachmentSelection.Count);
//    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, window.AttachmentSelection);
//    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(window.AttachmentSelection);
//end
//else if (context is Outlook._Inspector)
//{
//    MessageBox.Show("INSPECTOR");
//    Outlook._Inspector window = context as Outlook._Inspector;
//    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + window.AttachmentSelection.Count);
//    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, window.AttachmentSelection);
//    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(window.AttachmentSelection);
//}
//else if (context is Outlook._AttachmentSelection)
//{
//    MessageBox.Show("ATTACHMENTSELECTION");
//    Outlook._AttachmentSelection attSelection = context as Outlook._AttachmentSelection;
//    MessageBox.Show("Count: " + attSelection.Count);
//    GetAttachmentsInfo(item, attSelection);
//    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attSelection);
//}


  AttachmentSelection := nil;
  Context := OleVariant(RibbonControl.Context);
  if context.Class = 169 then // olAttachmentSelection = 169
  begin
    IDispatch(AttachmentSelection) := Context;
  end
  else
  if context.Class = 34 then // olExplorer = 34
  begin
    Explorer := OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
    //Explorer := Outlook2010.OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer;
    IDispatch(AttachmentSelection) := Explorer.AttachmentSelection;
  end;

  if Assigned(AttachmentSelection) then
  begin
    attList := TStringList.Create;
    Try
      attList.Clear;
      count := AttachmentSelection.Count;
      for I := 1 to count do
      begin
        AttFileName := AttachmentSelection.Item(I).FileName;
        //FileName    := GlobalTempDir + '\AttFile_' + IntToStr(I) + '.' + J_ExtFileName(AttFileName);
        TakeIt := True;
        if CheckIfAttachCanbeDroped(AttFileName) Then
        begin
          If (UpperCase(Copy(AttFileName,1,7)) = UpperCase('Image00')) And
             (GetMyFileSize(AttFileName) <= SMALL_FILE_SIZE) Then
            TakeIt := False;
        end;

        If Takeit Then
        begin
          JustFileName := CleanFileName(AttFileName);
          if Length(JustFilename) > MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH Then
          begin
            JustFileName    := Copy(J_FirstFileName(JustFileName),1,MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH) + '.' + J_ExtFileName(JustFileName);
          end;
          FileName     := GlobalTempDir + '\' +  JustFileName;
          if Length(Filename) > MAX_WINFILENAME_LENGTH Then
          begin
            FileLength := MAX_WINFILENAME_LENGTH - Length(j_PathFileName(Filename)) - Length(J_ExtFileName(Filename)) - 1 {for dot .};
            FileName   := GlobalTempDir + '\' + Copy(J_FirstFileName(JustFileName),1,FileLength) + '.' + J_ExtFileName(FileName);
          end;

          AttachmentSelection.Item(I).SaveAsFile(FileName);
          attList.Add(FileName);
        end;
      end;

      If attList.Count > 0 Then
        IndexAttachmentList(attList);
    Finally
      attList.Free;
    End;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You made this an answer. Is it satisfactory for you? I guess no. So you should delete that and either create a new specific question or add it as a comment in other answers, or edit the original question with more information. It is important to follow StackOverflow rules...

Comment: no. i just can't add comment so log :) and i dont know how to answer to your answer

Comment: i think add-in-express VCL for Delphi is not mainted as VB or c#. is stack in office2000

Comment: Never had t\o deal with it, but since you can only select a single attachment for preview, selection collection only reflects that attachment.

Comment: hi dimitry, i can select as much that i wont, but when i pass on the attachentlist (from the explorer) i alwes get 1.